# What does "would be in" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have been learning Python programming from a book and I came across a sentence which I can't understand!

> When you enter this code in the IDLE, it will automatically
>   indent, so be sure to press the backspace or delete key once you’ve
>   typed each print statement, so that your if, elif, and else statements
>   will start at the far-left margin. This is the same position
>   the if statement would be in if the prompt (>>>) were absent.

I just don't get this part:

> This is the same position the if statement would be in if the prompt (>>>) were absent.

What does "would be in" mean?

Comment: I edited your question to help others understand what you were asking. If you feel the edits were incorrect feel free to revert them.

Comment: @MrHen Well done Mr Hen. But I think we could achieve even more clarity with some punctuation. Try 'This is the same position the 'if statement' would be in, if the prompt...were absent.'

Comment: @WS2: I assumed the quoted portion was copied verbatim and did not edit it.

Comment: @MrHen Thank you MrHen,it's perfect.sorry if i bothered you,i'm just a newbie there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I text talks about a case like the following

```
if x:
   print("Hello")
else:
   print("Goodbye")
```

That's the correct way to format.
Wrong would be:

```
if x:
   print("Hello")
   else:
       print("Goodbye")
```

To prevent the wrong way from happening you have to hit the delete key after you wrote `print("Hello")` and pressed `<Enter>`.

What's with the prompt? If you are in IDLE the correct text will look like:

```
>>> if x:
        print("hello")
else:
        print("goodbye")
```

The sentence says that `if` would be at the same height as `else` if the `>>>` wouldn't be there. As far as python is concerned `if` and `else` are on the same level on indention.

Comment: Oh Thanks! i just don't know how to appreciate you! i got the meaning of concept.you really helped me,thank you very much.

Comment: @The_Diver: If the answer is what you were looking for you can check it as accepted. :)

Comment: @MrHen How do i do that?

Comment: Click on the green arrow to the left of the answer, just underneath the up/down arrows.